# How to connect to Kafka with no bootstrap servers?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka running with broker on a topic that needs credentials.
All the examples I see online require bootstrap servers in order to connect to kafka and none show how to use a broker.
I'm looking for settings to create a kafka reader to read whatever's written to topic.

Comment: What did you try so far? Which library? Kafka official client should work fine. Just pass the host port of your broker when creating Consumer.

Comment: The bootstrap servers usually _are_ brokers?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap server property is a list of one-to-many broker addresses. It is a required property, and you cannot create a Kafka client without bootstrap servers (i.e. a Kafka cluster).

Confluent maintains lots of code examples for various clients - https://developer.confluent.io/quickstart/kafka-local/